# CBC MAC forgery

Tags: block-cipher, mac, cbc-mac

$\text{CBC-MAC}$ is defined as follows:

- $\text{CBC-MAC}_k() = IV $
- $\text{CBC-MAC}_k(m_1, . . . , m_n) = E_k(m_n \oplus \text{CBC-MAC}_k(m_1, . . . , m_{n−1}))$

My lecture notes say that this is secure for fixed-length messages but forgeries are possible with arbitrary-length messages. I'm trying to come up with a proof for this.

Comment: Query for the MAC of 2 different messages, then what can you do by XOR'ng 2 separate message blocks to the CBC-MAC of the queried messages?

Comment: We had some Q/A for this. Well, did you look at Wiki page? It all explained there..